# Why am I unable to delete tabWidget in Qt Designer?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt Designer in combination with MSVC2019. I recently changed my form's base class from `QWidget` to `QMainWindow` manually by editing the .ui file, header, and constructor. In this form I have a `tabWidget`, which is now not able to be selected. It shows up in the object inspector and property editor, and I can edit its properties, but not select it. This is unlike all the other widgets in my form. When I right-click on the `tabWidget` in the Object inspector it gives the same menu options as a `QMainWindow` (Create Menu Bar, Add Tool Bar).

I have tried changing various object properties of the `tabWidget` and its main window but nothing has worked.

Here is the .ui region of interest. All I did was replace Widget with `QMainWindow` in line 4.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>campanel</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="campanel">
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1509</width>
    <height>984</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>FASTPLOTTER</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowIcon">
   <iconset>
    <normaloff>bigmoves.ico</normaloff>bigmoves.ico</iconset>
  </property>
  <property name="windowOpacity">
   <double>1.000000000000000</double>
  </property>
  <property name="autoFillBackground">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
  </property>
  <property name="tabShape">
   <enum>QTabWidget::Rounded</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="dockNestingEnabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="dockOptions">
   <set>QMainWindow::AllowNestedDocks|QMainWindow::AllowTabbedDocks|QMainWindow::AnimatedDocks|QMainWindow::ForceTabbedDocks</set>
  </property>
  <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
   <property name="enabled">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <property name="tabPosition">
    <enum>QTabWidget::West</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="currentIndex">
    <number>1</number>
   </property>
   <property name="documentMode">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="tabsClosable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="movable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="iolji">
    <attribute name="title">
     <string/>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
    <attribute name="title">
     <string/>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
  </widget>
```

Comment: You probably corrupted the `.ui` file by the manual editing. I would pull an older version out of your source control.

Comment: I assume you don't have a backup and are not using source control. Maybe someone can help if you add the text of the `.ui` file.

Comment: I do have source control ... but I think asking someone for help debugging the xml might be more beneficial in my case.

Comment: I will add it here

Answer (score 0):

`QMainWindow` is a special case of `QWidget`: it has a menu bar, a status bar, tool bars, can add dockable frames, and have a central-widget. While you can switch between `QWidget` and `QDialog` in UI files, when switching to `QMainWindow` you must embed all the content of previous widget into the `centralWidget`:

```xml
<widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <!-- size policy, geometry... -->
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
    <!-- size policy, layout, content of your previous QWidget -->
  </widget>
</widget>
```